# Python While Loop To Find Prime Does Not Terminate

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, primes

```
flag = 0
n = int(input('\nEnter whole number to check : '))
i = 2
while i <= (n/2):
    if (n%i) == 0:
        flag = 1
        break
if n == 1:
    print('1 is neither prime nor composite')
elif flag == 0:
    print(n,' is a prime number.')
elif flag == 1:
    print(n,' is not a prime number.')
```

Upon Entering a number >= 3, the program stalls and the cursor keeps blinking endlessly. I initially tries 277, then 13, then 5, then 3 - none of which gave a result even after a minute.

Entering 2 worked.

There must be something wrong with the code.

Comment: n/2 might not work so well in Python 3.

Comment: @user2864740 why ?

Comment: Because it’s not guaranteed to return an integer. For Python 3, n//2 (integer division) is usually ideal for these sorts of issues. In the conditional above it won’t matter, but if actually attempting to advance with such..

Comment: You have to add i+=1 to the loop.Unless i doesn't increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is not changing n or i, which are the conditions on which it stops.

I think the correct code should be:

```py
flag = 0
n = int(input('\nEnter whole number to check : '))
i = 2
while i <= (n/2):
    if (n%i) == 0:
        flag = 1
        break
    i += 1
if n == 1:
    print('1 is neither prime nor composite')
elif flag == 0:
    print(n,' is a prime number.')
elif flag == 1:
    print(n,' is not a prime number.')
```

Comment: How does it process 2 and 3 to be prime numbers then ?

Comment: Because at the start i is 2 which is greater than 3/2 and 2/2. In this case the loop won't start.

Comment: Aha ! Shit, am i stoned or what this is obvious shit

Comment: to save time for large numbers, you should do `while i <= (n**0.5)` instead of `while i <= (n/2)`

Comment: @aidan0626 n*0.5 or n**0.5 ?

Comment: @JakeFry `n**0.5`. you only need to check up to the square root of n

Comment: @aidan0626 Alrighty, is that so ? Hmm, maths is mysterious huh

Comment: @JakeFry: Not that mysterious. Any factor of `n` that's greater than the square root would definitionally be multiplied by some value *less* than the square root (the square root itself of course is multiplied by itself). So while factors greater than the square root may exist, you only care if there were factors at all, and testing the smaller possible values is sufficient to rule out any larger ones.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Woah, that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to check if a number entered is a prime number.

This code works:

```
# prime numbers are greater than 1, num is the entered number
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           break
else:
   print(num,"is a prime number")
```

At the end, you can also check for number 1 if you want.

Comment: The question could have been solved with minimal change to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works:

```
flag = 0
n = int(input('\nEnter whole number to check : '))
i = 2
while i <= (n/2):
    if (n%i) == 0:
        flag = 1
        break
    else:
        i += 1
    
if n == 1:
    print('1 is neither prime nor composite')
elif flag == 0:
    print(n,' is a prime number.')
elif flag == 1:
    print(n,' is not a prime number.')
```

This is because you need to increment `i` by 1 after every iteration, or your while loop will run endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("enter the number :")
prime = True
for i in range(2, num):
    if num%i==0:
        prime=False
        break
if prime:
    print(num" is a prime no")
else:
    print(num" is a not prime no")
```

Comment: Please at least make sure there are no syntax errors when submitting answers.

Comment: Hello, add any sort of description or at least comments for your code, please.